# Is it possible to send files and messages simultaneously in Java over a same socket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, messaging, file-transfer

Actually,I am trying to make a messaging app on Java.As i am beginner Stack-overflow and Internet are my primary resources.

I have successfully developed the app till the point where you can send messages to other person as well as receive messages.Also you can send files back and forth.But the problem i am facing is that when i try to send a file the connection is occupied by sending that file and no messages could be sent.Threading could also do nothing because my problem lies because of Socket being able to send a single item at a time.

> So i need a solution so that i am be able to send files and while the
>   files are being sent i am able to send messages.

Would i need to make two separate sockets over the same connection one for file transfer and one for sending messages?
Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You'll need to manually multiplex your data or use a separate socket for the transmission.

Comment: By separate socket you mean, a separate socket for file transfer and a separate for messaging?

Comment: Well obviously.

Comment: Echoing @Kayaman comment, it is usually much much easier to use a separate socket (and port) for different message types.

Comment: Does this mean i will have to make 2 server sockets  with different port numbers?

Comment: Yes (unless you implement a handshake protocol so individual connections on a single server port can take on different roles). Most peer-to-peer networking systems use separate socket connections for file transfers, where one messaging client acts as a file transfer server and the other messaging client acts as a file transfer client, so they can connect directly to each other.  If they can't connect that way (NAT/firewall blockage, etc), they just swap roles and try again. If that still doesn't work, they both connect to the messaging server to act as an intermediate proxy tunnel between them

Comment: If you don't want to go that route, you could just multiplex the file transfer data instead. Break up large file transfers into multiple smaller messages, each one tagged with a unique ID to identify the file transfer they belong to. Then messaging clients can exchange text and file messages on the same connection, sending file messages in between text messages and vice versa.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH GUYS.FINALLY IMPLEMENTED THAT ,YOU GUYS ARE SO HELPFUL.CHEERS